# Error al utilizar variable Javascript en Chart.js

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, chart.js

En Laravel, tengo definida una función en el blade para capturar el texto seleccionado en una lista desplegable:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function sacar_nombre(){
  var combo = document.getElementById('titulo');
  var titulo = combo.options[combo.selectedIndex].text;
}
</script>
```

Ahora quiero utilizar la variable "titulo" en un archivo Javascript externo enlazado con el blade.

```
 <script src="{{ asset('/js/grafico.js') }}"></script>
```

Pero al intentar mostrarla desde el fichero externo, me aparece lo siguiente: "[object HTMLSelectElement]"

El código del fichero externo es el siguiente:

```
 const CHART = document.getElementById("lineChart");
 console.log(CHART);
 let lineChart = new Chart(CHART, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: ["10/7/2017", "11/7/2017", "12/7/2017", "13/7/2017", 
      "14/7/2017", "15/7/2017"],
datasets: [
  {
    label: titulo,
    fill: false,
    lineTension: 0.1,
    backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)",
    borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
    borderCapStyle: 'butt',
    borderDash: [],
    borderDashOffset: 0.0,
    borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
    pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
    pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
    pointBorderWidth: 1,
    pointHoverRadius: 5,
    pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
    pointRadius: 1,
    pointHitRadius: 10,
    data: [10,6,9,8,8,7],
  }
]
```

}
});

La variable la utilizo en la etiqueta "label".

¿Alguien podría ayudarme?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function getText(elem) {
  alert(elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].text);
}
```

```html
<form>

  <select id="dropDown" onchange="getText(this)">
    <option value="1">Item 1</option>
    <option value="2">Item 2</option>
    <option value="3">Item 3</option>
    <option value="4">Item 4</option>
  </select>

</form>
```

Intenta probar con esto adaptando a tu código. Te aparece el alert cuando ocurre el evento '**onchange**' sobre el '**select**'

Comment: Hola, Thakur, gracias por contestar. Si, si ejecuto el alert desde el blade si que aparece correctamente el valord e la variable, pero si hago lo mismo desde el archivo .js me aparece el mensaje de  "[object HTMLSelectElement]"

Comment: Intenta poner el script después de que se cargue el html y despues haz un console.log();, sube una captura de console.log si es posible

Comment: Hola de nuevo, el console.log() no me arroja nada. El propio fichero js de Chart.js contiene un console.log y es cuando aparece la gráfica.